# OpenGraph API in ASP.NET same code on two computers, gives different result

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-opengraph

Colleague and I are working on same project, and share every line of code. We shared it via github, and then literally copy pasted from my machine to his (futile I know). Code is an asp.net form which takes booking.com url, passes it trough opengraph.io API, and returns results. Results I get are as expected, name of the hotel, location, stars. Results he gets are name of hotel: "help! which hotel is best", description: "some generic text". He's getting this same result no matter which url he pastes in.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "poiId,city,name,address,website,poiImg,rating,lon,lat,phone,email,category")] POI pOI)
        {
            var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(pOI.website);
            var ogKey = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpenGraphAPI"]);
            var requestUrl = "https://opengraph.io/api/1.1/site/" + url + "?app_id=" + ogKey;
            dynamic ogResults = new Uri(requestUrl).GetDynamicJsonObject();

            pOI.name = Convert.ToString(ogResults.hybridGraph.title);

            pOI.rating = Convert.ToDouble(pOI.name.IndexOf(' '));
            pOI.pOIDescription = Convert.ToString(ogResults.hybridGraph.description);
            pOI.poiImg = Convert.ToString(ogResults.hybridGraph.image);

            string gcUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=";
            string gcKey = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAPI"]);

            string key = "&key=" + gcKey;

            dynamic googleResults = new Uri(gcUrl + pOI.name + key).GetDynamicJsonObject();
            pOI.lon = Convert.ToDouble(googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
            pOI.lat = Convert.ToDouble(googleResults.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
            pOI.address = Convert.ToString(googleResults.results[0].formatted_address);


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.POIs.Add(pOI);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.category = new SelectList(db.Categories, "categoryId", "category1", pOI.category);
            ViewBag.city = new SelectList(db.Cities, "cityId", "city1", pOI.city);
            return View(pOI);
        }
```

In order to make api call, we use exactly the same code as this https://pastebin.com/6b2fLChA

I can only assume I've made some changes inside of files that we do not share via github, and forgot all about it. If anyone could give me a hint as to what to look for, what might be causing this problem, I'd be most obliged

Comment: Are you both using the same `ogKey` value?  It might not like being spammed.  Also, I was dealing with Google maps the other day, and your URL is out of date; the whole `sensor=true` variant is old hat (so I interpreted it)

Comment: Also, what is in the `ogKey` value that needs environment variables expanding?  Have you checked you've both got the same environment variables/settings at Windows level?

Comment: we just tried with his api key, still same result

Comment: api keys are stored in web.config which we're not pushing on to github so its locally available to us, while not being shared publicly. To my understanding this should not have anything to do with windows settings, and works fine for google API key on both machines.

Comment: `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` involves the local machine (or 'Windows settings').  If the API key is just a hex string, I don't see why it needs to be expanded with env variables anyway... but if you haven't compared the vars between both machines, then we'll never know.

Comment: Both are showing up fine in the code on both machines. It's just the response from api that is different

Comment: If `ogResults` is coming back differently, then it's the opengraph API or something in your browser/security settings; nothing anyone on here can really help with.